# SElinux config file missing

Tags: selinux

Trying to set up mail I found out I have important file missing or it seems I do.

First of all I have no selinux in `/etc/sysconfig` and in `/etc/selinux` there is folder `mls` and files  `restorecond.conf`  `restorecond_user.conf`  `semanage.conf` but no general conf file.

On command `sestatus` it says disabled.

On command `yum provides /etc/selinux/config`

```
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, refresh-packagekit
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
* epel: mirror.optus.net
selinux-policy-3.7.19-231.el6_5.1.noarch : SELinux policy configuration
Repo        : updates
Matched from:
Filename    : /etc/selinux/config



selinux-policy-3.7.19-231.el6.noarch : SELinux policy configuration
Repo        : base
Matched from:
Filename    : /etc/selinux/config



selinux-policy-3.7.19-231.el6_5.3.noarch : SELinux policy configuration
Repo        : updates
Matched from:
Filename    : /etc/selinux/config
```

On reboot it remains disabled after command `echo 1 > /selinux/enforce` before reboot.

I am on centos 6.5 and don't know how to check if SElinux is corrupted or not.

I don't think it exists in full:

```
-bash-4.1#  rpm -qa | grep selinux
libselinux-python-2.0.94-5.3.el6_4.1.i686
libselinux-utils-2.0.94-5.3.el6_4.1.i686
libselinux-2.0.94-5.3.el6_4.1.i686
-bash-4.1# rpm -q policycoreutils
policycoreutils-2.0.83-19.39.el6.i686
-bash-4.1# rpm -qa | grep setroubleshoot
-bash-4.1# semanage login -l 
-bash: semanage: command not found

CONFIG_SECURITY_SELINUX=y
CONFIG_SECURITY_SELINUX_BOOTPARAM=y
CONFIG_SECURITY_SELINUX_BOOTPARAM_VALUE=1
CONFIG_SECURITY_SELINUX_DISABLE=y
CONFIG_SECURITY_SELINUX_DEVELOP=y
CONFIG_SECURITY_SELINUX_AVC_STATS=y
CONFIG_SECURITY_SELINUX_CHECKREQPROT_VALUE=1
# CONFIG_SECURITY_SELINUX_POLICYDB_VERSION_MAX is not set
```

Comment: Please add the output of `grep -i selinux /boot/config-$(uname -r)` to your question. Is this a physical machine, a virtual machine, some type of hosting?

Comment: it is a vps have running.

Comment: I don't know if your provider supports SElinux out of the box. Either way, you don't seem to have a policy installed. Install one and relabel the filesystem to check that out.

Comment: I'm not sure what to install as I thought it came with centos by default. I might have to start from scratch but thanks.

Comment: You need to install a SELinux policy (`yum install selinux-policy-targeted`, then you'll need to relabel the whole filesystem, as this is a system that had SELinux **disabled** before. You need to be at least a little bit familiar with SELinux (i.e. do you want SELinux because the online guide says so?).

Comment: I don't think I want it at all. I am just trying to set up mail to us smtp but I've got myself in a world of trouble.

Comment: Your machine does not have SELinux enabled. You can just ignore it. Of course, you won't have the extra security provided by SELinux, nor the extra work needed to set it up and maintain it.

Comment: Optional tool `semanage` can be installed via `yum install policycoreutils-python`